# Which draft is closest to the C++14 standard?

Tags: c++, c++14

I've seen N3690, N4140, and N4296 mentioned in various places. I'm guessing it's N4140 because that was released in late 2014. N4296 seems to have stuff that isn't in C++14, like fold expressions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents

Comment: As of September 2016, the [isocpp website](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard) claims that N4296 is "the C++14 standard plus minor editorial changes", which is a false statement and is misleading a lot of people.  It's easy to verify by comparing N4140 (which is the standard with a different cover page) against N4296 and seeing that there are numerous significant changes.

Comment: The website doesn't seem to have a "contact us" or "report problem" link so if anyone knows how to contact whoever makes their website, that would be fantastic

Answer (score 26, accepted):

N3690 is an old committee draft for C++14; massive changes have been made since then (e.g., the removal of `<optional>` and `<dynarray>`), and it shouldn't be used for anything other than perhaps standard archaeology.

N3936 is the version that's sent out for final balloting (well, the version that's actually sent out is N3937, but the difference is basically a fancy cover page). That, with some [minor editorial fixes](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4139.html), became the C++14 IS.

N4140 is to C++14 what N3337 is to C++11 - C++14 plus some editorial changes.

N4296 is a later working draft incorporating additional proposals voted into the standard.

Comment: Some sources: [N3690 blog post](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/05/new-paper-n3690-programming-languages-c-committee-draft), [N3936 blog post](http://isocpp.org/blog/2014/03/n3936-38), [N3938 Editor's Report](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3938.html)

Comment: So based on that link, N4141 is the actual standard itself? (I have fortuitously acquired a copy...)

Comment: @Brian Yes, N4141 is the actual standard.

Comment: Regarding N4141 being the actual standard (apart from some "boilerplate") - see confirming Reddit comment that is apparently by N4141's author at https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/2sewtw/c14_published_by_iso_today/cnp1k28